# AWS S3 replication rule addition

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, replication

I have an s3 bucket where I have created several replication rules with separate prefixes to replicate data into a target bucket.
Now, I'm trying to create another replication rule with another prefix. Using AWS console, I can easily create a new replication rule. My requirement is to add the new rule using Python AWS SDK.
I'm using "PutBucketReplication" API for this purpose.
The problem occurs when I provide the replication configuration for new rule, it replaces all existing rules.
Is this the expected behavior?
Is there any way that I can use python to provide config for only the new rule to be added and not replace existing ones?

Comment: yes, it is a full update, try to use GetBucketReplication to fetch existing rules and then include them along with your new one in PutBucketConfiguration

Comment: @omuthu, I can do that. But I think replace will drop and create the same rule. My doubt is if there will be any gap b/w the drop and create. Can any files be missed during the command run?